# JSF 2. Strange behavior navigating between pages using IE7

Tags: jsf-2, internet-explorer-7

I have a web application where the first page is a login page, and once I am logged correctly, the main page is displayed. The page has a tabbed menu and **if the first time I click on one of the tabs, the main page is refreshed again instead of going to the requested page**. This occurs only on the first clic. The other times, everything works fine.

I texted it with Firefox, Chrome and IE7, and **this behavior only happened with IE7**. Why could this be? Where the error could be? Because I don't know what piece of my code should I copy here to clarify my question.

PD: I use a Filter and the main page uses a bean to populate a table. I also tried `<redirect/>` tag in `faces-cofig.xml`, and it solved the problem. But the page always showed the "Invalid User" popup contained in the login page. And finally, I discarded it.

### Update with some code

I think the problem isn't in the main page, because I replaced it by other pages and the behavior is the same... (Update 2) But with a simple html page it works fine.

*login.xhtml:*

```
<h:form id="login">
    <h:outputText value="#{msg['login.user']}"/>
    <h:inputText value="#{LogBean.name}" required="true"/>
    <h:outputText value="#{msg['login.password']}"/>
    <h:inputSecret value="#{LogBean.pass}" required="true"/>
    <p:commandButton id="botonAccesoPrim"
                    value="#{msg['login.enter']}"
                    action="#{LogBean.checkLog}"
            oncomplete="dlg1.show();">
</p:commandButton>

<p:dialog id="popup" 
      visible="#{LogBean.popup}"
      widgetVar="dlg1"
      modal="true">  
          <h:outputText value="Invalid User." />  
</p:dialog>
```

*LogBean:*

```
public class LogBean {

private String name;
private String pass;
private String validate = "";
private String popup = "false";

    //Getters, setters

public String checkLog() throws Exception {

    if (correctLog(md5Final)) {
        popup = "false";
        validate= "success";
        return validate;
    }
    else {
        popup = "true";
        validate = "fail";
        return validate;
    }
}

public boolean correctLog(String md5) throws SQLException {

    boolean correct = false;
    String sql = "SELECT ...";
    String passBBDD = null;

    cConexionOracle.conecta();
    ResultSet result = OracleConnection.query(sql);
    if (!(result.next()))
        return correct;
    else {
        passBBDD = result.getString("pass");
        if (md5.equals(passBBDD))
            correct = true;
    }
    OracleConnection.desconect();
    return correct;
}

public boolean isLogged () {
    return name != null;

}
```

*faces-config:*

```
    <managed-bean>
       <managed-bean-name>LogBean</managed-bean-name>  
       <managed-bean-class>LogBeanClass</managed-bean-class>  
       <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <managed-bean>
       <managed-bean-name>mainBean</managed-bean-name>  
       <managed-bean-class>MainBeanClass</managed-bean-class>  
       <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

<navigation-rule>
   <from-view-id>/HTML/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
   <navigation-case>
    <from-action>#{LogBean.checkLog}</from-action>
    <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/HTML/main.xhtml</to-view-id>
    <redirect/>
   </navigation-case>
   <navigation-case>
    <from-action>#{LogBean.checkLog}</from-action>
    <from-outcome>fail</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/HTML/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
   </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

*FilterLogin:*

```
public void doFilter (ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    if (req.getRequestURI().endsWith("login.jsf")) {
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
        return;
    }

    HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
    if (session != null) {
        LogBean BeanConnection = (LogBean) req.getSession().getAttribute("LogBean");
        if (BeanConnection != null && BeanConnection.isLogged()) {
            chain.doFilter(req, resp);
            return;
        }
    }
    resp.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/HTML/login.jsf");
}
```

*web.xml*

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>FilterLogin</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Filter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/HTML/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

*mainBean:* (Update 2)

```
private ArrayList<mainClass> mainList = new ArrayList<mainClass>();
private String name;
//...

//Getters, setters.

@PostConstruct
public void populateMainList() {

    String sql = null;
    if (name == null) {
        sql = "SELECT ...";
    }
    else
        sql = "SELECT ... LIKE '%"+name+"%'";

    OracleConnection.connect();
    ResultSet result = OracleConnection.query(sql);
    try {
        while(result.next()){
            mainClass main = new mainClass();           
            main.set...(result.getLong("someProperty"));
            mainList.add(main);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    OracleConnection.disconnect();
}

public ArrayList<mainClass> getMainList() throws SQLException {
    return mainList;
}
```

*main.xhtml*

```
<h:inputText id="search" value="#{mainBean.name}"> </h:inputText>
<h:commandButton id ="SubmitSearch" action="#{mainBean.seachButton}"></h:commandButton>    
<h:commandButton id ="new" value="New" action="#{sistemaBean.newButton}"> </h:commandButton>
<t:dataTable id="data" rows="1" value="#{mainBean.mainList}" var="item"
             width="95%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <t:column width="42%">
      <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="Name"/>
      </f:facet>
      <h:commandLink value="#{item.shortName}" action="#{detailledMainBean.mainDetail}">
        <f:param name="idMain" value="#{item.idMain}"/>
      </h:commandLink>
   </t:column>
   <t:column>
      <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="Description"/>
      </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{item.description}"/>
   </t:column>
</t:dataTable>
<t:dataScroller id="scroller" for="data"
                paginator="false" paginatorMaxPages="5"
                paginatorColumnClass="style"
                immediate="true"
                pageCountVar="pageCount" pageIndexVar="pageIndex"
                disableFacetLinksIfFirstPage="true"
                disableFacetLinksIfLastPage="true"
                renderFacetLinksIfFirstPage="false"
                renderFacetLinksIfLastPage="false"
                paginatorRenderLinkForActive="false"
                renderFacetsIfSinglePage="false"
                displayedRowsCountVar="true">   
   <f:facet name="previous">
      <t:outputText styleClass="style" value=" &laquo; Previous | "/>
      <t:outputText styleClass="style" value="Page #{pageIndex} / #{pageCount}"/>
   </f:facet>
   <f:facet name="next">
      <t:outputText styleClass="style" value=" | Next &raquo;"/>
   </f:facet>
</t:dataScroller>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is not answerable without seeing an SSCCE.

Comment: An SSCCE is supposed to be the **smallest possible but complete** code which we should be able to copy'n'paste'n'run **without** any further changes to see your concrete problem ourselves. There's relatively a lot of noise in the code posted so far (is it really mandatory to have an Oracle DB in order to reproduce your problem, for example? I don't think so) and I don't see any tabs. This seems to be just a copypaste of snippets of the real code instead of a fullworthy SSCCE which is carefully prepared on a blank playground environment.

Comment: In any way, I spot some oddities so far, but I can't relate them to the described symptoms.

Comment: Yes, it's not an especific code prepared on a blank playground environment. But I can assure you is not a copypaste of my code. As I said, I really don't know where is the problem and that was the reason I didn't put code the first time and I tried to simplify it because there may be many parties involved. Anyway, as always, thanks for keeping an eye on this. I'll try to reproduce the problem in a simpler example.

Answer (score 0):

IE7 and jsf 2 will give you various problems. We have not encountered this problem specifically but many others.

Our problems mostly boiled down to tables. JSF is pretty table centric and many components translates to html with one or several tables. For example we commonly had to use some extra css for aligns.

For some tables we had to set the table header width with javascript. Problem was IE7 broke the table because it couldn't determine header width.

Unsure if you can draw any clues from this. But I would advise you to think in terms of workarounds rather than "what's wrong with the code".

Comment: JSF is not table centric at all. The only components which "unnecessarily" generates a table are the `<h:selectManyXxx>` components, but they have nothing to do with general layout. It sounds more like as if you used `<h:panelGrid>` over all the place instead of `<div>` or `<h:panelGroup>` for some reason.